# Is there a way to automate perl script in call-back style on linux platform?

Tags: cron

I have a perl script that does polling a file's existence in every 600 seconds before it goes on to finish its task.  I am using crontab to schedule my script.  I wonder is there an event system on linux that I could register my perl script so that system does the call-back if the file exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.2/Inotify2.pm (Linux::Inotify2 - scalable directory/file change notification).

Also check out [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)

```
It consists of a daemon and a table manipulator. You can use it a similar way as the 
regular cron. The difference is that the inotify cron handles filesystem events rather 
than time periods.
```

Answer (score 2):

Inotify should be your friend for this one... . There seem to be perl bindings as well. Your kernel needs to support this though... .